# Как устранить ошибку laravel "Undefined index: id"

Tags: php, laravel

Как устранить ошибку `laravel "Undefined index: id"`? Возникает при попытке удаления страницы в админке.

```
if($request->isMethod('delete')) {
    $page->delete();
    return redirect('admin')->with('status','Страница удалена');
}


if($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $input = $request->except('_token');
    $validator = Validator::make($input,[
        'name'=>'required|max:255',
        'alias' => 'required|max:255|unique:pages,alias,'.$input['id'],
        'text' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: ларавель-то ту при чем? у вас просто в ассоциативном массиве нет такого значения, потому что, очевидно, вы в input его не передаете

Comment: 1) Просто возмутительно вы что не можете разнести в 2 маршрута ? зачем все пихать в один 2) Вам же вчера писали , у вас нету в Request id, видимо поэтому  и массив input не содержит id, сделайте `dd($input)` перед $validator